# Databricks Connect: spark-shell not found

Tags: databricks-connect

I installed databricks-connect already:

```
Requirement already satisfied: databricks-connect==13.3.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (13.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: py4j==0.10.9.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from databricks-connect==13.3.3) (0.10.9.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from databricks-connect==13.3.3) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from databricks-connect==13.3.3) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyarrow>=4.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from databricks-connect==13.3.3) (15.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio>=1.48.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from databricks-connect==13.3.3) (1.60.1)
Requirement already satisfied: grpcio-status>=1.48.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from databricks-connect==13.3.3) (1.60.1)
Requirement already satisfied: googleapis-common-protos>=1.56.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from databricks-connect==13.3.3) (1.62.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from databricks-connect==13.3.3) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: databricks-sdk>=0.1.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from databricks-connect==13.3.3) (0.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-auth~=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from databricks-sdk>=0.1.11->databricks-connect==13.3.3) (2.27.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.28.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from databricks-sdk>=0.1.11->databricks-connect==13.3.3) (2.28.2)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0.dev0,>=3.19.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from googleapis-co
mmon-protos>=1.56.4->databricks-connect==13.3.3) (4.25.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pandas>=1.0.5->databricks-connect==13.3.3) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pandas>=1.0.5->databricks-connect==13.3.3) (2024.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pandas>=1.0.5->databricks-connect==13.3.3) (2024.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google-auth~=2.0->databricks-sdk>=0.1.11->databricks-connect==13.3.3) (5.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from google-auth~=2.0->databricks-sdk>=0.1.11->databricks-connect==13.3.3) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<5,>=3.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from google-auth~=2.0->databricks-sdk>=0.1.11->databricks-connect==13.3.3) (4.9)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2.28.1->databricks-sdk>=0.1.11->databricks-connect==13.3.3) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2.28.1->databricks-sdk>=0.1.11->databricks-connect==13.3.3) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2.28.1->databricks-sdk>=0.1.11->databricks-connect==13.3.3) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests<3,>=2.28.1->databricks-sdk>=0.1.11->databricks-connect==13.3.3) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from rsa<5,>=3.1.4->google-auth~=2.0->databricks-sdk>=0.1.11->databricks-connect==13.3.3) (0.4.2)
user@v00000Y:~$
```

Now, I try to run `databricks-connect test` in order to connect to a remote clsuter, but I always get the following error:

```
x@vx:~$ databricks-connect test
* PySpark is installed at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark
* Checking SPARK_HOME
* Checking java version
openjdk version "1.8.0_392"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_392-8u392-ga-1~20.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.392-b08, mixed mode)
* Testing scala command
/bin/sh: 10: spark-shell: not found

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/databricks-connect", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/databricks_connect.py", line 311, in main
    test()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/databricks_connect.py", line 267, in test
    raise ValueError("Scala command failed to produce correct result")
ValueError: Scala command failed to produce correct result
```

What is missing/how can I install the spark-shell?

[Here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/databricks-connect/python/troubleshooting.html) it is stated:

> If you can’t run commands like spark-shell, it is also possible your
> PATH was not automatically set up by pip3 install and you’ll need to
> add the installation bin dir to your PATH manually.

Probably, this is the issue but where is the bin by default?

**Edit**: I used the same setup once with databricks-connect==11 which works and once with databricks-connect=13 which doesn't work: so it seems like spark shell is not inlcuded any more? If not what is the recommended way to include it?

**Edit**: I found out that pyspark is working! So with pyspark command that uses the `.databrickcfg` file with almost the same auth information it works. However, `databricks-connect test` fails? **Has the default Port be changed (`15001`) - I didn't see anything in the docu?**

Comment: Just to give you something: is the path correct? are the version correct? is spark installed?

Comment: I would assume a Path variable is missing, but I don't know here databricks-connect installs all the stuff